# How to set the text color of an SKLabelNode?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I have the following code, which doesn't seem to set the text color of scoreLabelNode to red.

```
func setUpScore() -> Void {
    scoreLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"MarkerFelt-Wide")
    scoreLabelNode.color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(1.0), green: CGFloat(0.0), blue: CGFloat(0.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0)) //How do I set this to red?
    scoreLabelNode.position = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX( self.frame ), 0.5)
    scoreLabelNode.zPosition = 100
    scoreLabelNode.text = String(score)
    self.addChild(scoreLabelNode)
}
```

How would I change the second line to get the score to display as red?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try (note the '**fontColor**', not '**color**')

```
 scoreLabelNode.fontColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, you took me past 10,000! (Mark the answer as "correct" too :)  )

Comment: so close , yet so far haha

Answer (score 1):

UIColor - `UIColor(red:R, green: G, blue: B, alpha: A)`

R,G,B are values between 0.0 to 1.0. When A stand to alpha(as well between 0.0 to 1.0).

Use this site to calculate the needed RGBA values :
http://www.colorpicker.com/

As for red, just change it to

```
scoreLabelNode.color = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
```

OR

```
scoreLabelNode.color = UIColor.redColor()
```

Try replacing

```
scoreLabelNode.color
```

To

```
**scoreLabelNode.fontColor**
```

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 10.3, Swift 4

```
scoreLabelNode.fontColor = UIColor.red
```